# WebSocket client can only connect to my server on localhost

Tags: python, websocket

I've been playing with websockets, and I've made a little client that I've put up on a website. When I try to connect from the website ( from my computer ) to a simple Python server on the same computer it works fine, connecting to localhost. However I cannot connect from another computer. I've seen this problem in quite a few questions here, but no solutions. According to [this](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/websockets/basics/#toc-proxyservers) website the problem probably can't be solved.

An alternative is socket.io, apparently, how can I use this for a client on a webhost? The GitHub socket.io page is quite vague on installation, at least for someone like me.

Well a simple example which works locally would be;

```
# Python server
import socket

sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.bind(("", 12345))
sock.listen(5)

newsock, addr = sock.accept()

print "Connection"

// Client
<script type = "text/javascript">

window.onload = function()
{

    // Works
    var sock = new WebSocket("ws://127.0.0.1:12345");

    // Doesn't work
    var sock = new WebSocket("ws://194.237.*.*:12345");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Could you give a minimal [non-]working example?

Comment: I guess you'd need to change `sock.bind(("", 12345))` to `sock.bind(("194.237.foo.bar", 12345))`.

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried binding to `0.0.0.0` ?

```
sock.bind(("0.0.0.0", 12345))
```

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that I had not opened the firewall for incoming connections to python.